# AWS Lambda gets executed 3 times

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, export, boto3

I have created a Lambda that subscribes to a specific log group and gets triggered everytime the log group is updated.

However, for some reason the Lambda gets triggered three times instead of just one. The Lambda is supposed to export log files to a S3 Bucket, and since it's triggered three times it exports the same logs three times. My first thought was that the Lambda was timing out and therefor was triggered multiple times but I've checked the logs and the execution is successful every time, and every execution has a unique RequestId.

Any thoughts about this? Any help is appreciated.

This is what my Lambda looks like:

```
import boto3
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    startTime = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours = 2)
    endTime = datetime.utcnow()
    cloudwatch = boto3.client('logs')
    response = cloudwatch.create_export_task(
        taskName = 'LogExport',
        logGroupName = '/aws/lambda/logGroupName',
        fromTime = int(round(startTime.timestamp() * 1000)),
        to = int(round(endTime.timestamp() * 1000)),
        destination='s3Bucket')

    return {
        'status': 200,
        'body': 'Lambda executed succesfully!'
    }
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you also shared your deployment configurations

Comment: Does this happen for every Lambda invocation, or just some? Does it always invoke exactly 3 times? Obviously this is a distributed system and has at-least-once semantics but I'd be surprised if it's duplicating invocations a lot.

Comment: What I experienced it always invokes three times when the lambda is triggered by an update in the log stream. When I run it manually it only invoke one time.

Comment: Can you share your Lambda's triggers from the console?